# How to move an element from inside to out side using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move the anchor tag outside p element, currently it is inside the p element. Here is my html:

```
<div class="the_excerpt">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried `append()` function but it is not working. I don't want to insert new anchor element. I just want to move anchor element outside p element.

```
$('.the_excerpt').find('p').append($('.the_excerpt').find('a'));
```

Can any one please guide me how can I fix, I will appreciate. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to append inside the `p` tag, since `a` is inside `p` it doesn't make any change for the markup. So change your code as follows

```js
$('.the_excerpt').append($('.the_excerpt p a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the_excerpt">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

---

Or you need to use the **[`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)**

```js
$('.the_excerpt p a').appendTo('.the_excerpt');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the_excerpt">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('a').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="the_excerpt">
    <p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

you can try using [.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

> Description: Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

```
$('.the_excerpt').find('p a').appendTo($('.the_excerpt'));
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/o6nktzc1/)

Answer (score 0):

// Clone element and remove if needed

var cloneEle = $('.the_excerpt').find('a').clone().remove();

//append clone element where you desire

$( ".the_excerpt" ).after( cloneEle  );// if you want to aapend after .the_excerpt

or

$( ".the_excerpt" ).append( cloneEle  ); //if outside only p tag